# Delphi - How to use more defined values in conditional compilation

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction

Can I combine some IFDEFS in my source?

For example:

```
{$IFDEF INCOMING or OUTGOING}
...
{$ENDIF}
```

Thanks for your help:
   dd

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`$IF`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IF_directive_%28Delphi%29) with `Defined()` rather than `$IFDEF`:

```
{$IF Defined(INCOMING) or Defined(OUTGOING)}
...
{$IFEND}
```

Comment: But note that that won#t work wit hearly versions of Delphi. There it is very easy to do:

Comment: @rudy did part of  your comment get lost?

Comment: Heck yeah. My finger slipped off my magic mouse when I wanted to cancel it, the page changed and I couldn't find my reply back. I thought I had actually managed to cancel it.<g>

Comment: In never versions, use `{$ENDIF}` instead.

Comment: Additionally, you can prefix each Defined() with not if you want to check multiple defines are not actually defined. So, for example, {$IF not Defined(INCOMING) and not Defined(OUTGOING)}

Answer (score 14):

Alternative, for older versions:

```
{$IFDEF INCOMING}
  {$DEFINE INCOMING_OR_OUTGOING}
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF OUTGOING}
  {$DEFINE INCOMING_OR_OUTGOING}
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF INCOMING_OR_OUTGOING}
...
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: What is the definition of 'older'?

Comment: @Andreas `$IF` was added in Delphi 6

Comment: @Andreas: those which don't have [CONDITIONALEXPRESSIONS](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Conditional_compilation_%28Delphi%29) defined. That's [pre-Delphi 6](http://books.google.com/books?id=V9t0lA-BPUAC&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=%22delphi+6%22+CONDITIONALEXPRESSIONS&source=bl&ots=4-UBsNal5r&sig=e-8cfyKVxOe5Z_wDZ1jtqKCyycw&hl=en&ei=s0ThTf3YLI-cOsLenNUG&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22delphi%206%22%20CONDITIONALEXPRESSIONS&f=false).

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe the $IFDEF supports it, but the $IF does.
http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirsifdirective_xml.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation of David's answer using 'not'.

I use this when I want to disable the splash screen on my apps while in debug mode. It prevents me from accidentally leaving the splash disabled if I forget to undefine NOSPLASH in the release build.

```
  {$IF not (Defined(NOSPLASH) AND Defined(DEBUG))}
     //code to create splash 
  {$IFEND}
```